# multiply() in numpy python

Tags: python, performance, numpy

It seems to me there are two versions of numpy function `multiply()`:

1. `c = multiply( a, b )`
2. `multiply(a, b, c )`

My questions is two fold:

1. What is the difference between the two versions?
2. I need to use `dot()` function, and I know `c = dot( a, b)` works. But `dot(a, b, c)` does not.

Answer (score 6):

1. The difference between the two versions of `multiply()`:

   ```
   c = multilpy(a, b)
   ```

   multiplies the arrays `a` and `b` element-wise, creating a **new** array as result.  The name `c` is bound to this new array.  If `c` pointed to a different array before, this might or might not trigger garbage collection of the array `c` pointed to before, depending on whether other references to this array still exist.

   ```
   multilpy(a, b, c)
   ```

   multiplies the arrays `a` and `b` element-wise, storing the result in the **existing** array `c` (which must have suitable dimensions).  No new array object is created, but rather an existing array is changed.  Apart from the different semantics, this variant is faster if `c` already points to an array of suitable type and dimension, because no new array is allocated.  This variant also can reduce memory usage.
2. Isn't actually a question.  Yes, `dot()` does not have a three parameter form.  It isn't a ufunc and doesn't follow the usual broadcasting rules -- it can't because of the semantics of a dot product.

   **Edit**: Starting with NumPy 1.6, `dot()` actually does have a three-parameter form with similar semantics as explained above.  (For what it's worth, it is still not a ufunc.)

Answer (score 1):

There is only one version of all of the standard numpy ufuncs -- using dot as an example

```
Type:           builtin_function_or_method
Base Class:     <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
String Form:    <built-in function dot>
Namespace:      Interactive
Docstring:
    dot(a, b, out=None)

Dot product of two arrays.

For 2-D arrays it is equivalent to matrix multiplication, and for 1-D
arrays to inner product of vectors (without complex conjugation). For
N dimensions it is a sum product over the last axis of `a` and
the second-to-last of `b`::

    dot(a, b)[i,j,k,m] = sum(a[i,j,:] * b[k,:,m])

Parameters
----------
a : array_like
    First argument.
b : array_like
    Second argument.
out : ndarray, optional
    Output argument. This must have the exact kind that would be returned
    if it was not used. In particular, it must have the right type, must be
    C-contiguous, and its dtype must be the dtype that would be returned
    for `dot(a,b)`. This is a performance feature. Therefore, if these
    conditions are not met, an exception is raised, instead of attempting
    to be flexible.
```

If you provide the optional third agrument with the correct dtype and storage order, it will work:

```
In [78]: a=np.array([1.,2.,3.,4.])

In [79]: b=np.diag(a)

In [80]: c=np.empty_like(a)

In [81]: np.dot(a,b,c)
Out[81]: array([  1.,   4.,   9.,  16.])

In [82]: np.dot(a,b)
Out[82]: array([  1.,   4.,   9.,  16.])
```